# How to implement smart primary keys

Tags: sql, salesforce

I listened to [salesforce architecture demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WODJ7St-m9U). If you listen at `14:15` he says they put extra information in the primary key such as the orgid, tableid, and rowid. So I investigated this id on the salesforce website and got an example url. here is what the url looks like: `https://na24.salesforce.com/011a00000E80Z`. Is there a way to implement something like this in sql server?

Comment: You can put anything you like in a URL and interpret it however you want.  And your PK should be driven by your business requirements. I don't think he meant 'rowid' in the Oracle sense (since they can change), but that URL seems to identify a particularly row via their own algorithm; which happens to be related to the PK in their (all-stirng!) table. Maybe explain what your actual real problem is and what you've done to solve it, rather than referring (vaguely, really) to another system?

Comment: If information from other columns are required in the primary key, then have a composite primary key.